# Protocol buffer extension not recognised on OSX

Tags: c++, encoding, cross-platform, protocol-buffers, message

I have a Protocol Buffers protocol defined as follows:

```
package pkg;

message Query {
    optional uint32 basicfield = 1;

    extensions 100 to max;
}

message Point {
    optional int32 x = 1;
    optional int32 y = 2;
}

message SpecificQuery {
    oneof specific_oneof {
        Point centre = 1000;
        Point corner = 2000;
    }

    extend pkg.Query {
        optional SpecificQuery specific_query = 101;
    }
}
```

I am using Protocol Buffers 2.6.1rc1 (and I have also tested with 2.6.0), since I want to try to use the `oneof` feature. Everything is 64-bit C++. `make check` passes on both platforms. If I send and receive both on Linux (compiling with gcc 4.6.3), it seems to work fine. If I receive one a Mac (OSX 10.9, compiling with Clang under XCode), however, it does not seem to recognise extensions.

This is the receiving code:

```
if (query.ParseFromArray(array, len))
{
    if (query.has_basicfield())
    {
        printf("Basicfield: %d", query.basicfield());
    }

    if (query.HasExtension(pkg::SpecificQuery::specific_query))
    {
        // Never reached on OSX
        // Reached on Linux
        pkg::SpecificQuery* sqy = query.MutableExtension(pkg::SpecificQuery::specific_query);

            if (sqy && sqy->specific_oneof_case() == pkg::SpecificQuery::kcentre)
            {
                // Also reached on linux
            }
    }
}
```

If I print the Protocol Buffer object with `PrintDebugString()`, I get this, as expected on Linux:

```
basicfield: 1234
[pkg.SpecificQuery.specific_query] {
  centre {
    x: 50
    y: 150
  }
}
```

But on a Mac, I see:

```
basicfield: 1234
101 {
  1000 {
    1: 50
    2: 150
  }
}
```

Moreover, `query._extensions_` is empty, but `query._unknown_fields_` contains `101`, indicating the extension registry seems not to be working. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow, the definition of `SpecificQuery::specific_query` is not being linked into your app. It could be that your compiler is so smart it has managed to optimize away all the calls you made to the protobufs, and your linker is so smart it managed to drop the whole object file from your output program. If you `.pb.o` somehow doesn't get linked into the program, then its initializers will never run, therefore any extensions it defines will never be registered, and you'll see the behavior you're seeing.

One way to force linkage is to place a dummy usage inside some other code that you know is getting properly linked in. For example, you could add this line to the function you posted:

```
SpecificQuery::default_instance();
```

This function call has no side effect, but is implemented in the `.pb.cc` file and thus will force the `.pb.o` to be linked.

Comment: It was exactly a linking issue, but it was because I'd managed to get the protobuf-lite dylib linked by my XCode project in addition to the normal protobuf one, which was evidently being used in preference!